# Issue with getting source code from dynamic generated content using Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I want to scrape FDA for anything from Applicant 'Apple Inc.'

This is the search page:
https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfpmn/pmn.cfm

I can use Selenium to fill in Applicant Name and submit the form, but the result source is now showing the generated results only the original form.

I see that if I change the Results per Page after submitting the form, the url changes to:
https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfpmn/pmn.cfm?start_search=1&Center=&Panel=&ProductCode=&KNumber=&Applicant=Apple%20Inc&DeviceName=&Type=&ThirdPartyReviewed=&ClinicalTrials=&Decision=&DecisionDateFrom=&DecisionDateTo=11%2F09%2F2023&IVDProducts=&Redact510K=&CombinationProducts=&ZNumber=&PAGENUM=500

Using this results somewhat works, but only as long as things are cached. Starting a new session using that url just default backs to the original url.

What am i missing??

This is my full script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
        
def main():
    url = "https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfpmn/pmn.cfm"
    
    payload = {
        'Applicant': 'Apple Inc.'
    }
    # Initialize Firefox web driver
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    try:
        # Navigate to the webpage
        driver.get(url)
            
        # Find the form elements and fill them out
        for key, value in payload.items():
            input_element = driver.find_element(By.NAME, key)
            input_element.send_keys(value)
     
        # Submit the form
        input_element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

        # Wait for the page to load (you may need to adjust the timeout as needed)
        driver.implicitly_wait(1000)

        # Get the page source after form submission
        page_source = driver.page_source

        soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')
  
        # Now you can use Beautiful Soup to extract information from the HTML content
        # For example:
        matching_tr_elements = soup.find_all('tr', {'bgcolor': '#ffffff'})
        for tr_element in matching_tr_elements:
            print(tr_element)
        
    finally:
        # Close the browser window
        driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```